# Angular: How to serve on Flask and route to different endpoints/paths?

Tags: angular, flask

I am trying to make an Angular application served with Flask to load the Angular app login page. Using just the `https://domainname/` works fine, but I cannot route to `https://domainname/login`.

#### Steps to reproduce:

- Clear browser cache
- Open new tab and navigate to `https://domainname/login`
- Returns 404

Initially I used another solution, but trying things along the way, I ended up with the approach suggested by Stack Overflow question [**Python (Flask) serving Angular project's index.html file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824239/python-flask-serving-angular-projects-index-html-file)

#### Flask Routes

```
@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET'])
def static_proxy(path):
  return send_from_directory('./dist/', path)


@app.route('/')
def root():
  return send_from_directory('./dist/', 'index.html')
```

The production build from the Angular app goes directly in the `dist` folder. The `https://domainname/` request hits the first route and actually I couldn't see the second route working. So when I type `https://domainname/login` it hits the first route and of course it returns `404` because there is no file with name login in the 'dist' folder. So the question is, how to route to paths like:

- `https://domainname/login`
- `https://domainname/contacts`
- `https://domainname/contacts/map`

The other configuration that I have tried, and it has the same behavior, is using `Blueprint`. I don't understand why, still doesn't work with the `/login` path, because in this version should return the index.html file and it should work on the client side, correct? (here the angular app is build to static/dist)

```
main.py
from app.api_default import api as default_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(default_blueprint)
```

...

```
app/api_default/__init__.py
STATIC_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.pardir, 'static/dist')
api = Blueprint('default', __name__, static_folder=STATIC_FOLDER, static_url_path='')
from . import routes
```

...

```
app/api_default/routes.py

@api.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@api.route('/<path:path>')
def route_path(path):
  return api.send_static_file('index.html')


@api.route('/')
def home_paths():
  return api.send_static_file('index.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular applications are single-page applications (SPA). A SPA is a web application or web site that interacts with the user by dynamically rewriting the current page rather than loading entire new pages from a server [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)].

Once you have successfully served the `index.html` page from Flask and loaded the Angular application, routing is handled by the [Angular Router](https://angular.io/api/router).

See [**Routing & Navigation**](https://angular.io/guide/router)